# Why can't I select an input box with a directly copied selector in Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Up until now I've been able to select input boxes to type in using Puppeteer however when I use waitForSelector, I Can't even find this element.

It's directly copied selector is

```
#root > div > main > div > main > div._pw._fj > div > div > input
```

The full html element is here. I'm beyond confused as to why it won't be found.

```
<input data-test-id="player_search:Input" type="text" role="search" class="_bw _eq _aj _nw _jx _db _ck _aw _ox _oy _oz _jw _w _pa" placeholder="Find a player" title="Find a player" value="">
```

Comment: Unfortunateyly there's not enough information here to offer any advice. Please share a [mcve] with the site you're scraping and the desired output.